# Git submodule causing Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] Android sdk 21

Tags: android, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, git-submodules

I am working on an app and trying to use the new material design, aka sdk version 21.
I had everything working fine, and then wanted to at a fab (floating action button) using [this library](https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button).

I added this library as a submodule, using

```
git submodule add https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button
```

while under C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName

My file structure looks like so

```
ProjectName
    app
    floating-action-button
```

**The issue**
Before everything was totally fine, I was able to build and run the project.
But, ever since adding this submodule, when trying to run it, I get the error

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
```

So I'm thinking it has to do with the submodule, but I'm not sure how.

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mayuonline.ribbit"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:+'
}
```

**app/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="resume.kelseyhrubes">

    <uses-sdk tools:node="replace" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**f-a-b/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.0'
    }
}

def isSnapshot() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains('SNAPSHOT')
}

def gradleMvnPush = new File(buildDir, 'gradle-mvn-push.gradle')
if (!gradleMvnPush.exists()) {
    buildDir.mkdirs()
    ant.get(src: GRADLE_MVN_PUSH, dest: gradleMvnPush)
}

setProperty('GRADLE_MVN_PUSH', gradleMvnPush)

subprojects {
    group GROUP
    version VERSION_NAME

    apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'

    if (name.startsWith('lib')) {
        apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    } else {
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion COMPILE_SDK_VERSION as int
        buildToolsVersion BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion MIN_SDK_VERSION as int
            targetSdkVersion TARGET_SDK_VERSION as int
            versionCode 1
            versionName '1.0'

            // workaround for https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962
            buildConfigField 'boolean', 'SNAPSHOT', isSnapshot().toString()
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    if (isSnapshot()) {
        apply plugin: 'robolectric'

        dependencies {
            // NOTE workaround for sdkmanager plugin
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'

            androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
            androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3'
            androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8'
        }
    }
}
```

**f-a-b/AndroidManifest.xml (probably a clue here, I (tried to) bold the areas that Android Studio has turned red**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=" **http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android** "
          package="com.shamanland.fab.example">

    <application
        android:name=" **.ExampleApplication**  "
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:icon** ="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        **android:theme** ="@style/AppTheme"
        **android:allowBackup** ="true"
        >
        <activity android:name=".ExampleListActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=" **.ExampleDetailsActivity** "/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have a *strong suspicion* that the submodule was added incorrectly.

Really all I want is to use a fab in my app, if anyone can help me figure out what may be wrong, with adding the submodule, or something with my build.gradle, that would really be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually caused by deploying an APK built with "compileSdkVersion n" to a device or emulator with an API level less than "n".  Is your emulator at the right API level?

Comment: I'm testing the device on my Nexus 7, running 4.4.4

Comment: 4.4.4 is API level 19. In your "build.gradle" file you've set the "minSdkVersion" to 21. An APK generated that way won't run on a 4.4.4 device. Just change your "build.gradle" to use API level 19. –  AndroidGuy 19 mins ago

Comment: The strange thing is, everything ran fine before on my device, I haven't touched app/build.gradle. It was only after adding the submodule that the error appered