# How to include project on git into new android project

Tags: android, git

How I can include existing project into my android app.
following is the one  i want to use:

https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add your project as a submodule of your android app repo.
See for instance [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26702376/6309):

```
cd C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName
git submodule add https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk
```

> file structure:

```
ProjectName
    app
    dhis2-android-sdk
```

Comment: hey Vonc can you please tell me step by step as i am a newbie here.

Comment: @Sourabh do you have a  `C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName` which is a git repo?

Comment: Yes i have found that what next to do

Comment: I am trying to add the git command: git submodule add https://github.com/dhis2/dhis2-android-sdk  under : C:\Users\USER\AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName  but i got this following error:'git' is not an internal or external command.

Comment: @Sourabh "git' is not an internal or external command" means that your environment variable path is not set or you donot have git installed

Comment: @Sourabh unzip (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/) https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.4.6.windows.1/PortableGit-2.4.6-5th-release-candidate-64-bit.7z.exe anywhere you want and add it to your PATH